# What is a X-Mas Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property, seasonal

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a X-Mas Word™.

Use the following examples to find the rule.

[image]

Here is a CSV version:

```
X-MAS WORDS™, NOT X-MAS WORDS™
WHISKEY*, RUM
CHRISTMAS, HANUKKAH
HAPPY*, SAD
JOY, FUN
CHOCOLATE*, COCOA
YOGHURT*, MILK
IDIOT*, DUMB
GLAMOUR, FLAIR
BABY*, CHILD
EXOTIC*, PLAIN
WINTER*, SPRING 
SNOWBOARDING*, SWIMMING
LIGHT, DARK
FOOD*, DRINK
JINGLE*, MUSIC
SANTA CLAUS, MICKEY MOUSE
TOY, BALL
HEAT*, CHILL
SNOW, SEA
FAILURE, SUCCESS
DROP, DRIP
DEER*, MOOSE
```

*Extra X-Mas Word™

The puzzle relies on the series' inbuilt assumption, that each word can be tested for whether it is a X-Mas Word™ without relying on the other words.

These are not the only examples of X-Mas Words™, many more exist and can be found.

Comment: X-Tra X-Mas Word, surely? :-)

Comment: Well, now that you said it... :)

Comment: Can the words be tested for X-mas and X-tra X-mas wordiness independently of each other?

Comment: @boboquack What do you mean independently? Whether a X-mas word can be tested independently from another X-mas word or whether a X-mas word can be tested independently from an X-tra Xmas one? Each word can be tested independently for X-mas-ness, if this is the question. If you know the rule, of course.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Maybe add that to the question, saying something like that is common in what is an N? puzzles

Answer (score 14, accepted):

X-MAS Words are the ones ->

> Whos letter values if multiplied gives a "0" at the end.

Examples - >

> **WHISKEY** ($23*8*9*19*11*5*25$) - 43263000
>  **CHRISTMAS** ($3*8*18*9*19*20*13*1*19$) - 364927680
>  **HAPPY** ($8*1*16*16*25$) - 51200
>  **JOY** ($10*15*25$) - 3750
>  **YOGHURT** ($25*15*7*8*21*18*20$) - 158760000

Not X-Mas Word's

> **RUM** - 4914
>  **HANUKKAH** - 2276736
>  **SAD** - 76

Extra X-Mas Word's are the ones ->

> Whose letter values if multiplied gives double and triple "0"'s i.e. "00" or "000" etc.

Examples

> **HAPPY** - 51200
>  **IDIOT** - 97200
>  **EXOTIC** - 972000
>  **HEAT** - 800

These are called X-MAS because -

> As @oleslaw commented - X indicates roman 10 and hence trailing 0's. Also as per OP's comment, Extra X-mas are called extra as they are divisible by 10 twice or more

Comment: After you give a couple of examples and explain the name, I will accept your answer. :)

Comment: "X" in **X**-mas could mean "10" in roman numbers. It would explain the "0" ending. (and double "X" **X**-tra **X**-mas for double "0")

Comment: @MariaDeleva- Updated with the examples :) Not sure if I am close to guessing the reason why X-Mas though.

Comment: @Techidiot oleslaw is right. Because the final values are achieved by using multiplication and are divisible by 10. Extra - simply means the multiplied value of the letters of the word is divisible by 10 multiple times (2 or more).

Comment: so basically the must contain one or more `{J,T}` or more  {E,J,O,T,Y} and one of {B,D,F,H,J,L,N,P,R,T,V,W,Z}